# BIP1042I: Command deprecated, please use policy projects instead

Tags: ibm-app-connect

Kindly help me i am stuck in Configuration of Event monitoring i am using this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qZN9zq6h1a8&t=299s  from youtube and i am stuck in one commad that i am sharing in the image on App connect 12 console.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybLzg.png)
I am configure the event for logs so what will be the command that i confugure in app connect.

I am expecting that somebody share us the full command of app connect.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.